# Matrix entries using a single function

Tags: matrices, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is it possible to write the following matrix as a single function, without any explicit if condition mathematically?

For, $$1 \leq i,j\leq n,$$
$$A(i,j)=\begin{cases} 
2 ~~\text{if}~~ i \neq j \\
1 ~~\text{if}~~i=j
\end{cases}
$$

Mathematically it should be written as 
$$A(i,j) = f(i,j)$$

It can be combination of minimum, maximum, floor, ceil, trigonometric functions.

Comment: How about $f(i,j) = \lceil |\sin(i-j)| \rceil + 1$

Comment: Why not $\;2-\delta_{ij}\;$ with $\delta$ the [Kronecker delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) ?

Comment: The Kronecker delta is not on OP's list of allowed functions, and is basically just a short notation for the conditional. - But it was also my first thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without trigonometric functions:
$$
A(i,j)=1+\frac{|i-j|}{\max(1,|i-j|)}.
$$
Since the absolute value is not among the allowed functions, you can replace $|i-j|$ by
$$
|i-j|=\max(i-j,j-i),
$$
so
$$
A(i,j)=1+\frac{\max(i-j,j-i)}{\max(1,i-j,j-i)}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

As $0$ is the only integer that is a "multiple" of $\pi$, this should work.
$$
A(i,j)=2-\lfloor|\cos(i-j)|\rfloor
$$

If the absolute value is not allowed:
$$
2-\lfloor\max(0,\cos(i-j))\rfloor
$$
should work.